# Partitions - how to create a new partition from unused space?

Tags: partitioning

I wasn't too sure where to post this so I'll just post it here.

It seems I have quite a bit of space left on my hard drive. How do I create partitions from this unused space? I presume the 8gb is my RAM. But I've got another 12GB unused partition. How do I create a drive from this partition (e.g. F:)?

[image]

Comment: This space isn't unused. There's a ("recovery") partition on it.

Comment: Of course the recovery partitions is not technically required.  If you have a copy of the media and all the drives and software to reinstall the system from scratch then you can dump this partition.

Comment: That's an awful lot of unused partitions - has that system been set up to dual boot?  Looks like those could be Linux partitions?

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on the partition name and format it. If prompted about formatting recovery drive, ignore it. you will have regained your 12GB

Answer (score 0):

You do not have any unused space. The 8gb is not your system memory. It is an unmounted primary partition. The first two are system partitions.

3-5 are recovery partitions. You can tell Windows ( from the control panel) not to reserve so large a percentage for recovery purposes to reduce the size of one. The other two are likely your manufacturer's and your security software's recovery programs. You may not need all three. Try to determine which program created which partition and choose at least one to retain in the event of an emergency before you destroy or shrink them.

The 8GB is the interesting one. Windows has not assigned it a drive letter, however it does have an entry in your partition table. This is also a good candidate, as it is 100% free. Again, take a look at the files inside and see if you can ascertain what it was created for and by whom (try checking who the owner is). If it is empty and not owned by some critical process, then format it with the NTFS. If you have any extra blocks from shrinking/deleting recovery partitions combine them into this single partition. Windows should assign it a letter automatically.